Racket datum->syntax with unquote splicing
In Racket, I am trying to use s-exp to build a new language. So the macro to build an if statement is:
(define-syntax (buildif stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    ;split the body (stx) and split into parts
    [(_ condition (then-expr ...) (else-expr ...))
     ;build the if statement
     #'(if condition
          (begin then-expr ...)
          (begin else-expr ...))]))

The problem I have is that I want to convert the syntax into datums using syntax->datum or syntax->list to modify the syntax. However, I cannot then convert the datum->syntax using the unquote splicing to insert the modified values.
I want to apply a macro that takes a list of datums and returns a list of datums such that '((+ x y) (- x y)) gives '((- x y) (+ x y)). I want to use this modified list as the values for the if statement
(define-syntax (rev-if stx) ;modified if
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ condition (then-expr ...) (else-expr ...))
     ;convert the syntaxes to datums to manipulate
     (let ((con (syntax->datum #'condition))
           (newthen (opswap (syntax->list #'(then-expr ...))))
           (newelse (opswap (syntax->list #'(else-expr ...)))))
       ;I want to convert the datums back to syntax to execute
       (let ((composed `(if ,con (begin ,@newthen) (begin ,@newelse))))
         (datum->syntax #f composed)))])) 

If I use datum->syntax I get this error:
if: unbound identifier;
also, no #%app syntax transformer is bound in: if
If I try using:
(syntax/loc stx ;build the syntax for the if
         (if ,con
             ;,@ unquote splicing to place syntax of datums into syntax
              (begin ,@newthen)
              (begin ,@newelse)))

I get this error:
unquote: not in quasiquote in: (unquote con)
What I am trying to do is to execute an if branch in reverse. I have defined += -= methods etc. So opswap takes a list such as '((+= x 1) (-= y 2)) and converts it into '((+= y 2) (-= x 1)). I put both branches in begin so that it will execute if passed just one expression or multiple.
(define-for-syntax (opswap oppslist)
     (begin
       (for/list ([item (reverse oppslist)]) ;for every item in the reverse of the opperation list
         (begin
           (cond
           [(and (pair? item) (eq? (car item) '+=)) (cons '-= (cdr item))]
           [(and (pair? item) (eq? (car item) '-=)) (cons '+= (cdr item))]
           [(and (pair? item) (eq? (car item) '*=)) (cons '/= (cdr item))]
           [(and (pair? item) (eq? (car item) '/=)) (cons '*= (cdr item))]
           [(and (pair? item) (eq? (car item) 'displayln) item)];make an exception for displayln as they are diagnostic or display
           [(and (pair? item) (eq? (car item) 'swap) item)] ;call the swap method (it is it's own inverse
           [else item]))))) ;if not assume that it is a method call


The first argument to datum->syntax tells the syntax expander the lexical context that the returned syntax should have, i.e., which identifiers are bound. The way this is communicated is via an existing syntax object; the first argument's lexical context is copied to the return value.
Passing #f as the first argument means that no identifiers are in scope, not even if, which is why you get the error "if: unbound identifier".
One way to solve the problem is to use the lexical context at the site of the macro invocation (k).
(define-syntax (rev-if stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(k condition (then-expr ...) (else-expr ...))
     (let ((con (syntax->datum #'condition))
           (newthen (opswap (syntax->list #'(then-expr ...))))
           (newelse (opswap (syntax->list #'(else-expr ...)))))
       (let ((composed `(if ,con (begin ,@newthen) (begin ,@newelse))))
         (datum->syntax #'k composed)))]))

You will generally make life easier for yourself and eliminate potential scoping errors by avoiding syntax->datum, when possible. Instead, use syntax-case and with-syntax to deconstruct syntax, and to reconstruct syntax use

syntax (#')
quasisyntax (#`)
unsyntax (#,) and
unsyntax-splicing (#,@)

syntax->list is ok because it doesn't act recursively and returns a list of syntax objects.
Here's what that might look like:
#lang racket

(define-syntax-rule (+= var val) (set! var (+ var val)))
(define-syntax-rule (-= var val) (set! var (- var val)))
(define-syntax-rule (*= var val) (set! var (* var val)))
(define-syntax-rule (/= var val) (set! var (/ var val)))

(define-for-syntax (opswap exprs)
  (for/list ([expr (reverse (syntax->list exprs))])
    (syntax-case expr ()
      [(op var val)
       (and (identifier? #'var) (eq? (syntax->datum #'op) '+=))
       #'(-= var val)]
      [(op var val)
       (and (identifier? #'var) (eq? (syntax->datum #'op) '-=))
       #'(+= var val)]
      [(op var val)
       (and (identifier? #'var) (eq? (syntax->datum #'op) '*=))
       #'(/= var val)]
      [(op var val)
       (and (identifier? #'var) (eq? (syntax->datum #'op) '/=))
       #'(*= var val)]
      [else expr])))

(define-syntax (rev-if stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(k condition (then-expr ...) (else-expr ...))
     (with-syntax ([(newthen ...) (opswap #'(then-expr ...))]
                   [(newelse ...) (opswap #'(else-expr ...))])
       #'(if condition
             (begin (void) newthen ...)
             (begin (void) newelse ...)))]))

> (define x 1)
> (rev-if #t ((+= x 1) (/= x 5)) ())
> x
4


Are there any other lexical context indicators? If I use variables such as (+ x 1) that are defined is there a way to include those without an unbound identifier error? I also need to perform the operations in reverse, so if ((+ x 1) (- y 1)), the operation order is ((+ y 1) (- x 1)). Which is why I used the syntax->list as its a list of operations so I can reverse that list before swapping the operators

Apologies for the confusion. I've updated my answer. Does rev-if require both branches to be begin expressions? It would help if you provided your code for opswap and explained precisely what it is supposed to do.

To my knowledge, datum->syntax can only take lexical context from an existing syntax object.

Thanks for your help! I have tried to explain the best I can. opswap is taking the datum list and converting them into the opposite operator in reverse order. syntax->list converts then-expr ... into the list. But I am not sure how to either modify opswap to operate over syntax or create the syntax

Thanks for the clarification. What should (rev-if #t (+= x 1) #f) expand to? What should (rev-if #t (begin (+= x 1) (begin (+= y 2) (+= z 3))) #f) expand to? What should (rev-if #t (let () (+= x 1) (+= y 2)) #f) expand to?

I have restricted the s-exp implementation so using #lang s-exp "lang.rkt" to only allow certain methods to be used not all of Racket. Currently, begin let etc. are not provided. I am trying to work with the provided += -= *= /= and swap which swaps two values (I also have methods to define values)

Interesting. Is this valid? (rev-if #t ((+= x 1) (-= y 2)) (#f)). It would be helpful if you provided one or more example usages of rev-if.

Also, how are the operators +=, -=, etc., defined?

From your answer I have been able to achieve the functionality I set out. I have marked this as resolved. I greatly appreciate all your help

@JayDee Thanks. I made some assumptions and updated my answer with a mostly complete, working solution. You weren't far off with opswap, just needed to use syntax-case instead of cond.

That’s exactly what I’ve done. I really appreciate your time. You’ve been a big help. Thank you
